# Service fails to start when external log config file is involved

Tags: python, windows-services, pyinstaller, python-logging

I am using PyInstaller to bundle my multi-module Python app into a `one-file` exe. The entry point for this app is a module extending `win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework` -- so this is meant to run as a Windows service. Problem arises when I try to furnish a user configurable logger ini file with this app. In my main module, I set up the logger thus,

```
log_file_path = path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), 'logging.conf')
logging.config.fileConfig(log_file_path)
```

My PyInstaller command is the following:

```
pyinstaller -F <main-file>.py -n <exe-name> --hidden-import=win32timezone --add-data "logging.conf;."
```

Once packaged, I install the produced exe as a service and it successfully registers as a Windows service. However when I attempt to start it, it fails.

The interesting bit is that an empty log file is created in my configured location. So this implies that 1) The application did read my config file, and 2) There's no permissions issue here. Has anyone tried to set up something like this that could help shed light on what I might be missing?

Comment: hi what's the exception?

Comment: @jspcal I simply get the "service did not respond to the control request in a timely fashion" message from Windows. No exception or call stack is indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the one-file option with PyInstaller, we cannot validly use the `__file__` variable in our code to identify the bundled app or its location. Instead, PyInstaller sets special system variables at runtime, like `sys._MEIPASS` and `sys.executable`; which specify the temporary folder created by the bootloader to run the app, and location of the frozen executable (the bootloader), respectively.

Once I changed my path manipulation to use these variables to locate the log config file, the file is successfully read and the service works.